# Android uses-feature in tablet

Tags: android

I have android app with next permissions

```
<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

But in my samsung tablet i've got `This app is not comptable with your tablet. Android 4.2.2`

What "uses-feature" I should set as

> android:required="false"   ?

Comment: Does your tablet has a vibrator?

Comment: no, how can I switch off this requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure it's that. uses-feature directive are more blocking though. do you have any?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the Samsung tablets can **vibrate** or not, but if they can't, you will need to switch

```
<uses-permission
```

to

```
<uses-feature
```

And use the ***required flag***. If it is not required, it won't be necessary and will not be filtered because of it. You will have to handle this for tablets that can't vibrate in code if part of your app handles vibrate. If it is not vibrate, then **another one of these** will be causing the issue and will need to change to uses-feature.

[See Uses-Feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

On a secondary note, you should also check you're *supporting the larger screen sizes* with and not accidentally omitting *xlargescreens* from the manifest.